# finding the limit of a series and testing for convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, trigonometric-series, absolute-convergence

$\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}\cos(kπ) + \sin(k(π/2))$ = undefined, so the series diverges.

---

How is this undefined? isn't undefined when you get 0/0?

How would I go about finding out what happens as k→∞

Comment: what is the limit of $\cos(k\pi)$ when $k\to\infty$?

Comment: it oscillates between -1 and 1...

Comment: then the limit doenst exists because if the limit exists is an unique point. To see this you need the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit. Now apply this reasoning to your formula seeing what happen with it values.

Comment: The sequence (not "the series") is 1, 0, 2, -2, 1, 0, 2, -2, 1, etc. This makes for four different limit points, thus, the sequence diverges (and already two different limit points would be enough to conclude, of course).

Comment: $\epsilon - \delta$ is a bit to harsh for this, at least for my taste. Would go with Cauchy instead, might be more helpful in the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $k \to \infty$, the cosine and the sine functions oscillate,
so the limit does not exist.

Comment: so if the series oscillates, we say its undefined?

Comment: As we couldn't know the exact value of the function, we say that its undefined

Comment: "more quickly" No, they oscillate forever at the same speed.

Comment: "undefined" Hmm, this is ambiguous. Rather, say that **the limit does not exist**.